# Generate unique invoice number for each permit where permits have multiple line items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It seems like this should be a classic issue that has already been solved, but maybe I'm just not wording my searches correctly.

My query is like this (this is a simple example, the actual query is more complex):

```
select
  permit,
  customer,
  --need help here-- as invoice,
  row_number() over (partition by permit order by permit) as line_item,
  fee
from
  tableA
```

This is what I need to be returned, but I can't get the invoice generation to come out right:

```
permit        customer   invoice   line_item   fee
-----------   --------   -------   ---------   -----
MTR20181000   8214       7510000   1           5.00
MTR20181000   8214       7510000   2           10.00
MTR20181000   8214       7510000   3           25.00
MTR20181013   1225       7510001   1           10.00
MTR20181025   5655       7510002   1           20.00
MTR20181025   5655       7510002   2           5.00
```

I've tried using the over() function, much like I did with the line_item, but I can't seem to get it to auto increment based on the permit number. The invoice has to start with 751xxxx.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to do what you want:

```
select permit, customer,
       (7510000 + dense_rank() over (order by permit)) as invoice,
       row_number() over (partition by permit order by permit) as line_item,
       fee
from tableA;
```

Comment: Yep, this works! I'll have to go look at the dense_rank() function. _Obviously_ I'm not familiar with this. Thank you for the quick response

Comment: @Jfire: Keep in mind that this will only work for the first 9999 permits!

Comment: Christian, thank you for the heads up. I guess the department only needs this for one year and they only get 15-20 of these on average.

Comment: @Jfire Be aware this is not repeatable if permit changes or you don't add in order